# Building an API vs. Syncing Database Across the Cloud

Tags: web-services, ipad, api

I have a client interested in building an iPad app that gathers information and matches people based on some criteria.

The API method involves building a service on a server to handle requests sent by the iPad.  The data and data manipulation are all done on the server.  The iPad simply pulls and pushes data to/from the server.  No (or little) data is stored on the iPad - it's main function is to serve as the user interface.

The data sync method involves keeping all data manipulation on the iPad and using a cloud service such as iCloud or Dropbox to sync the local MySQLite database(s).  The data, therefore, is stored on the iPad as well as the cloud servers.

What are some pros and cons to developing an API vs. syncing data across the cloud?

My instinct tells me the data sync method is not best, especially for scalability and the possibility of syncing conflicts.  However, I'm curious what the SO community thinks.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

iCloud is on a per user basis so you can not sync one persons data to some other persons iCloud account so you can not use it as I think you are wanting to . The service you want to use is push to push notification API to push data to the iphone or iPad as you can push the same data to all users and you would need to use another API to get the data off the phone or iPad to your server . iCloud is used for syncing data from one device to another that is owned by the same user so if your app had a database of data on my iPad it will sync that data to my iPhone .